# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when editing a record using a DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

Good day. I am coding using asp.net C# and I am having hard time to edit my records saved in sql server database using gridview. Here is my code

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    camConnection.ConnectionString = SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString;
    camSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand, camConnection);
    camSqlDataAdapter.Fill(camDataSet);
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    TextBox pid1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
    TextBox pname1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
    TextBox pdesc1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
    TextBox pquan1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
    TextBox pprice1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0];

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    camConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("update productInfo set ProductName='" + Convert.ToString(pname1.Text) + "', Description='" + Convert.ToString(pdesc1.Text) + "', Quantity='" + Convert.ToString(pquan1.Text) + "', Price='" + Convert.ToString(pprice1.Text) + "' where ID='" + pid1.Text + "' ", camConnection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    camConnection.Close();
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

When I execute the code and edit the record in gridview, then click on the update link, an error occured saying:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index

Comment: At what line does that error occur, probably one of the `row.Cells[n].Controls[n];`? Place breakpoints, step through your code, search the web for the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some fields are null in your Gridview.
So when you write:

```
TextBox pid1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
```

the code is looking for some value. If `row.Cells[1].Controls[0]` is null it will show an out of range exception. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Probably some fields are null in your Gridview. So when you write:

TextBox pid1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
the code is looking for some value. If row.Cells[1].Controls[0] is null it will show an out of range exception. Hope this helps.